# Docker : Running image does not produce Pandas Data frame output on host computer

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I have a Python script that extracts data from website using API key, formats into Pandas data frame and then exports this data frame to excel file. Based on the Python code this file is stored on C:/Python folder. Name of excel file is Sid.xls
I have created a docker image and have this script inside my container. When the run the image it does not generate this excel file.

## Python Code ( "EIA.py")

```
import eia
import pandas as pd

api_key = "mykey"
api = eia.API(api_key)

series_storage = api.data_by_series(series='NG.NW2_EPG0_SWO_R48_BCF.W')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(series_storage)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1.columns = ['Date', 'Value']
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].str[:-3], format='%Y %m%d')
df1.to_excel("C:/Python/Sid.xls")
```

## Docker file

```
FROM python
ADD .  /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY EIA.py /code
RUN pip install EIA-python
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install xlwt
CMD ["python","EIA.py"]
```

## Expected results.

When my image runs it should generate Sid.xls on my laptop.

Comment: You should add a shared volume to save your output dataframe to. Your output is currently saved in your image.

Comment: How can I add a shared volume? Would you please help me as I am devastated :)

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Can you provide me a exact syntax for my question? I am using docker run -v C:/Sid :/app image name but when I run I don't see an excel file generated.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `-v` option can work on Windows because of the directory path (C:). However, you do something like `docker run -v host-folder:docker-folder image-name` and use `cp file docker-folder` for your docker entrypoint.